# Where can I find actual ANTLR Objective-C examples?

Tags: objective-c, parsing, antlr, grammar

There are pages that indicate ANTLR works with Objective-C, but I can find no documentation or examples of actually *using* ANTLR with an Objective-C target. I even dug through the source code and have found no examples.

Any guidance, anyone?

Answer (score 1):

The parser generator that emits Objective-C code is old and doesn't work. You'll have to use the C generator, and the C generator's documentation is worse than useless.

Comment: @BartKiers I thought I remembered one. Will edit answer to fix - thanks!